# Embed Auto-import function in Vim Editor

Tags: vim

Is there any way to embed Auto-import function in Vim editor, like the way we use `Ctrl + Shift + O` in Eclipse? 

**UPDATE**

I use Vim editor version 7.3 to develop Android application by using Java on Linux

Comment: Language? System? Vim version? Your question is too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here comes the plugin: [JavaImp](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=325) :)